# Sobel edge detection filter not correct output: can it be because of some parameters

Tags: image-processing, fpga, xilinx, xilinx-edk, sobel

I am using http://shakithweblog.blogspot.kr/2012/12/getting-sobel-filter-application.html for zynq processor.
I am using his filter design in the PL part and running the hdmi test. 
I am inputting this file [image]
and my filtered output is coming like this: 
[image]

I am trying to display 1920 * 1080 pixels.
Now lets assume its difficult for you see exactly my design/ or download the design and check it or even you are not familiar with the zynq board and all but is it possible to make some guess that why the filter output could be like this? and what can I try to make it correct. I need some suggestions.

Comment: may be your chip is not configured properly, any edge detector would not give such an output.

Comment: I agree with Bharat... i cant think of any edge detection method that will produce such output.

Comment: This to me looks like random noise, so you probably have some memory problem or major timing violations or your IC is configured wrong.